# Section name in header also without numbering sections

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

my problem I try to have the section names in the header. Some sections are not numbered, however do I want them as well in my header.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rmfamily \small \nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headsep}{.5cm}
```

This is the codes I use for my headers and footers.

```
\section*{List of Symbols and Abbreviations}
```

The list of symbols doesn't have to be numbered, so I put an asterisk after `\section`. Is there a way to have  "List of Symbols and Abbreviations" in the header?

This is the code to copy+past and try it out by yourself..

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rmfamily \small \nouppercase \leftmark}

\setlength{\headsep}{.5cm}


\begin{document}

\section*{Abstract}

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\section*{List of Symbols}
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\newpage                        
 
\section{Basics}
\newpage

\section*{appenix}
\end{document}
```

as you can see the section abstract, list of symbols and appenix is not displayed in the header, whereas the section introduction is displyed

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a small, yet complete, code?

Comment: From the two answers posted it's clear that we've understood different things about what you want in the table of contents. I'm assuming, since the list of figures is in the TOC, that you want unnumbered sections in the TOC. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I understand that you use the starred commands to avoid having those section appearing in the TOC.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rmfamily \small \nouppercase \leftmark}

\setlength{\headsep}{.5cm}


\begin{document}

\section*{Abstract \protect\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract} }

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\section*{List of Symbols\protect\markboth{List of Symbols}{List of Symbols}}
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\newpage                        
 
\section{Basics}
\newpage

\section*{Appendix \protect\markboth{Appendix}{Appendix}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! that worked

Comment: @caarloXY I know you say that this worked, but with this solution your List of Figures appears in the table of contents, but the List of Symbols doesn't. Is this really what you want? It's certainly not very consistent. (This isn't meant as a criticism of Simon's answer, as they can easily modify it to work.)

Comment: I checked my document again, it doesn't appear. anyways, Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to deal with this sort of thing is to simply change the `\secnumdepth` counter in the different parts of the document and not use `\section*` at all and instead just use `\section`. Then the correct elements will appear both in the TOC and in the headers without any manual intervention other than changing the sectioning depth.  For the appendix I've used the `\appendix` command that changes the section numbering there too.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rmfamily \small \nouppercase \leftmark}

\setlength{\headsep}{.5cm}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % turn of numbering of sections in the frontmatter
\section{Abstract}
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{List of Symbols}
\newpage
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % turn on numbering in the main matter
\section{Introduction}
\newpage                        
 
\section{Basics}
\newpage
\appendix
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % turn it off again in the back matter
\section{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image: abstract header]
[image: list of symbols header]

Comment: good idea, however I have set my \secnumberdepth already at 3. because I want my section to be numbered

Comment: Try the whole code

Comment: Ouh, I see now. thanks !

Comment: And this puts everything in the TOC which I think you want?